# How to fetch image from cloudinary server when using ckeditor with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ckeditor, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am using Rails 4. I am trying to create a blog using rails. So I started with ckeditor(editor), carrierwave(upload image), cloudinary(to store image). I pushed my code in Heroku. Now in ckeditor toolbar I select image icon and then from upload tab I choose a file and upload file by clicking "send it to server" and I can see the image uploaded in my cloudinary account. Now the problem is when I "Browse server" to fill the url in ckeditor it shows error. The error in my log is

```
"ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `path' for #<Cloudinary::CarrierWave::CloudinaryFile"
```

and In browser I got this error:
[image]

In localhost:
[image]

My codes are below:

ckeditor_picture_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  # Include RMagick or ImageScience support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageScience

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/ckeditor/pictures/#{model.id}"
   # "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # [:extract_content_type, :set_size, :read_dimensions].each do |method|
  #   define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
  #     send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
  #     {}
  #   end
  #   alias_method_chain method, :cloudinary
  # end

  process :extract_dimensions

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [118, 100]
  end

  version :content do
    process resize_to_limit: [800, 800]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.image_file_types
  end
end
```

models/ckeditor/picture.rb

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  mount_uploader :data, CkeditorPictureUploader, mount_on: :data_file_name

  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end
end
```

assets/javascripts/ckeditor/basepath.js.erb

```
<%
  base_path = ''
  if ENV['PROJECT'] =~ /editor/i
    base_path << "/#{Rails.root.basename.to_s}/"
  end
  base_path << Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
  base_path << '/ckeditor/'
  %>
  var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '<%= base_path %>';
```

assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2011, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
  // config.language = 'fr';
  // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  config.allowedContent = true;

  // Toolbar groups configuration.
  config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    // { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
    // { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] }
  ];

  config.toolbar_mini = [
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] }
  ];
};
```

How can I solve this issue? Please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader` to look similar to this:

```
class CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  [:extract_content_type, :extract_size, :extract_dimensions].each do |method|
    define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
      send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
      {}
    end
    alias_method :"#{method}_without_cloudinary", method
    alias_method method, :"#{method}_with_cloudinary"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.attachment_file_types
  end
end
```

After that, you will find another error.
I found that in [Ckeditor::AssetResponse#asset_url](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/asset_response.rb#L89) 
method, the `asset` object is not reloaded, so `asset.content_url` will always be nil thus caused the error. I fixed it like this:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  ...
  def url_content
    url(:content) || begin
      if persisted?
        reload
        url(:content)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And similarly for `Ckeditor::AttachmentFile` class if you have it.

Comment: I tried adding the code `class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset` by creating file in  `models/ckeditor/picture.rb` didn't help. I put logger statements, but don't see them in server log. Not sure if I'm placing them in right folder structure.